# RSA encrypt file or text

Tags: swift, rsa

[Download XCode project](https://www.zahedi.pro/dl/RSAProblem.zip)

[image]

I encrypt message and save it to file. If when I decrypt file the same time of encrypt file, decrypt successful but if other time decrypt function return nil.

I use this class for encrypt and decrypt.

```
class Crypt{

    // MARK: Public

    // MARK: Internal
    var publicKey, privateKey: SecKey?
    var publicKeyData, privateKeyData: Data?
    var statusCode: OSStatus?


    let publicKeyAttr: [NSObject: NSObject] = [
        kSecAttrIsPermanent:true as NSObject,
        kSecAttrApplicationTag:"com.aparnik.ios.books.public".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)! as NSObject,
        kSecClass: kSecClassKey, // added this value
        kSecReturnData: kCFBooleanTrue] // added this value
    let privateKeyAttr: [NSObject: NSObject] = [
        kSecAttrIsPermanent:true as NSObject,
        kSecAttrApplicationTag:"com.aparnik.ios.books.private".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)! as NSObject,
        kSecClass: kSecClassKey, // added this value
        kSecReturnData: kCFBooleanTrue] // added this value

    // MARK: Private

    // MARK: Initializer
    init() {
        self.generateRSAKey()
    }

    // MARK: Function
    fileprivate func generateRSAKey() {

        var keyPairAttr = [NSObject: NSObject]()
        keyPairAttr[kSecAttrKeyType] = kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA
        keyPairAttr[kSecAttrKeySizeInBits] = 1024 as NSObject
        keyPairAttr[kSecPublicKeyAttrs] = publicKeyAttr as NSObject
        keyPairAttr[kSecPrivateKeyAttrs] = privateKeyAttr as NSObject

        statusCode = SecKeyGeneratePair(keyPairAttr as CFDictionary, &publicKey, &privateKey)

        if statusCode == noErr && self.publicKey != nil && self.privateKey != nil {
            print("Key pair generated OK")
            var resultPublicKey: AnyObject?
            var resultPrivateKey: AnyObject?
            let statusPublicKey = SecItemCopyMatching(publicKeyAttr as CFDictionary, &resultPublicKey)
            let statusPrivateKey = SecItemCopyMatching(privateKeyAttr as CFDictionary, &resultPrivateKey)

            if statusPublicKey == noErr {
                if let publicKeyData = resultPublicKey as? Data {
                    self.publicKeyData = publicKeyData
//                    let publicKeyXor = xor(publicKeyData)
                    //print("Public Key: \((publicKeyData.base64EncodedString()))")
                    //print("Public Key xor: \(publicKeyXor.base64EncodedString())")

                }
            }

            if statusPrivateKey == noErr {
                if let privateKey = resultPrivateKey as? Data {
                    self.privateKeyData = privateKey
                    //print("Private Key: \((privateKey.base64EncodedString()))"
                }
            }
        } else {
            //print("Error generating key pair: \(String(describing: statusCode))")
        }
    }


    func xor() -> Data{

        var publicKeyXor: Data = Data()

            if (self.publicKeyData != nil) {

                //print("Public Key: \((publicKeyData.base64EncodedString()))")
                //print("Public Key xor: \(publicKeyXor.base64EncodedString())")
                publicKeyXor = self.publicKeyData!

                let base: Int = 53
                let length: Int = 40
                let magic: Int = 95

                for i in 0..<length{
                    let index = i + base
                    publicKeyXor[index] = self.publicKeyData![magic] ^ self.publicKeyData![index]
                }
            }


        return publicKeyXor
    }

    // decrypt
    func decryptWithRSAKey(_ encryptedData: Data, padding: SecPadding = .PKCS1, rsaKeyRef: SecKey? = nil) -> Data? {
        let rsaKeyRef = rsaKeyRef ?? self.privateKey!
        let blockSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(rsaKeyRef)
        let dataSize = encryptedData.count / MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size

        var encryptedDataAsArray = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: dataSize)
        (encryptedData as NSData).getBytes(&encryptedDataAsArray, length: dataSize)

        var decryptedData = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 0)
        var idx = 0
        while (idx < encryptedDataAsArray.count ) {
            var idxEnd = idx + blockSize
            if ( idxEnd > encryptedDataAsArray.count ) {
                idxEnd = encryptedDataAsArray.count
            }
            var chunkData = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: blockSize)
            for i in idx..<idxEnd {
                chunkData[i-idx] = encryptedDataAsArray[i]
            }

            var decryptedDataBuffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: blockSize)
            var decryptedDataLength = blockSize

            let status = SecKeyDecrypt(rsaKeyRef, padding, chunkData, idxEnd-idx, &decryptedDataBuffer, &decryptedDataLength)
            if ( status != noErr ) {
                return nil
            }
            let finalData = removePadding(decryptedDataBuffer)
            decryptedData += finalData

            idx += blockSize
        }

        return Data(bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>(decryptedData), count: decryptedData.count)
    }

    // remove padding
    func removePadding(_ data: [UInt8]) -> [UInt8] {
        var idxFirstZero = -1
        var idxNextZero = data.count
        for i in 0..<data.count {
            if ( data[i] == 0 ) {
                if ( idxFirstZero < 0 ) {
                    idxFirstZero = i
                } else {
                    idxNextZero = i
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        if ( idxNextZero-idxFirstZero-1 == 0 ) {
            idxNextZero = idxFirstZero
            idxFirstZero = -1
        }
        var newData = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: idxNextZero-idxFirstZero-1)
        for i in idxFirstZero+1..<idxNextZero {
            newData[i-idxFirstZero-1] = data[i]
        }
        return newData
    }

    // encrypt
    func encryptWithRSAKey(_ data: Data, padding: SecPadding = .PKCS1, rsaKeyRef: SecKey? = nil) -> Data? {
        let rsaKeyRef = rsaKeyRef ?? self.publicKey!
        let blockSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(rsaKeyRef)
        let dataSize = data.count / MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size
        let maxChunkSize = padding==SecPadding.OAEP ? (blockSize - 42) : (blockSize - 11)

        var dataAsArray = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: dataSize)
        (data as NSData).getBytes(&dataAsArray, length: dataSize)

        var encryptedData = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 0)
        var idx = 0
        while (idx < dataAsArray.count ) {
            var idxEnd = idx + maxChunkSize
            if ( idxEnd > dataAsArray.count ) {
                idxEnd = dataAsArray.count
            }
            var chunkData = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: maxChunkSize)
            for i in idx..<idxEnd {
                chunkData[i-idx] = dataAsArray[i]
            }

            var encryptedDataBuffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: blockSize)
            var encryptedDataLength = blockSize

            let status = SecKeyEncrypt(rsaKeyRef, padding, chunkData, idxEnd-idx, &encryptedDataBuffer, &encryptedDataLength)
            if ( status != noErr ) {
                NSLog("Error while encrypting: %i", status)
                return nil
            }
            encryptedData += encryptedDataBuffer

            idx += maxChunkSize
        }

        return Data(bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>(encryptedData), count: encryptedData.count)
    }

}
```

save this message to file:

```
    let message = "This is my message. asdfl;jas f;lkajsdf la;skfj asd;lkfj sa;dlkfjsad ;lkfj dsal;kfj daslk;fjds flkjas dfjkdfgjkhdfs gjklsdf lkgjhdfs klgj dfskljg fdslkjg dsfjklg dfskjlg dfskljg fdskljg fdskjlgn dfsjlknv sflkdjnv ldksfjnv dfsjnvdkfjsghlfsjkdgh fdskljgh dsfkljgh dfslkjghdljkfs sdfkljsadf dsaf;lkasdjf sad;lfjk as;ldkfjas d;flkjasd flk;asdf lkjha sdflhjka sdklgha fkljgh fsdkljg alkjfh aslkjdf asldkjfh asdljkfasdlkjfhas ldfh ash aslkj asdlkj aslkjchads lkjchadslkfjhsadlkfjhsad flkjasdh flkjashdf lkjadhsf lkjasdhf lkjashdf lkjasdhf lkadsjfhadslkfjhiuwlhoewiqufhopweif asjkbdsa kjfasdlkfja sdljkfhs alkjfh adsjkfhas ldfkjhas ldkfjhajlsfh alsjdfhadlsfhlasjdkfjhsad fljkls "

        let encryptData: Data? = self.crypt.encryptWithRSAKey(message.data(using: .utf8)!)

        let fileName = "file.enc"
        let dir = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory,
                                               in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
if let fileURL = dir?.appendingPathComponent(fileName).appendingPathExtension("dgk") {

            // Write to the file Test
            do {
                //                try encry.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
                try encryptData?.write(to: fileURL)
            } catch {
                print("Failed writing to URL: \(fileURL), Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
            }

        }
```

if I decrypt file at this time decrypt is success. but when I close the program and open it and decrypt file, decrypt method has been failed.

```
if let fileURL = dir?.appendingPathComponent(fileName).appendingPathExtension("dgk") {
            var encryptDataFromFile: Data?
            do {
                encryptDataFromFile = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
                if let decryptData: Data = self.crypt.decryptWithRSAKey(encryptDataFromFile!){
                    let decryptString: String = String(data: decryptData, encoding: .utf8)!
                    print(decryptString)
                }
                exit(0)
            } catch {
                print("Failed reading from URL: \(fileURL), Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
```

[Download XCode project](https://www.zahedi.pro/dl/RSAProblem.zip)

Comment: What is the file size in bytes? Note that the data size RSA can encrypt is less than the key size. Even for raw RSA a 1024-bit key is limited to less than 128-bytes. In general asymmetric encryption such as RSA is not used to encrypt data, data is in general encrypted with symmetric encryption such as AES.

Comment: Try using the debugger to isolate the core issue, and provide an MWE. You've shared lots of code to read and keep in mind. Also, what zaph said: what you are doing is very non-standard. That said, one thing I note is: why do you remove padding yourself?

Comment: @zaph the size is 768 bytes. I'm be careful about size, and I'm minus 11 for padding, and use chunk for limitation. my problem is: the first time when I save encrypt message  work, but  when I comment save to file section and just read it from file and decrypt, decrypt doesn't work.
because the data from server encrypted with RSA then I must use it.

Comment: @Raphael I'll check it. I'm deleting 'removePadding' in code.

Comment: Please, [no code dumps](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:

1. Each time the app is launched it generates a new key pair, thus the previously encrypted data can not be decrypted with the new and different private key. The keys (or at least the private key) must be saved for future use.
2. You are mis-using RSA by encrypting in chunks! When the data size is to large, or in general encrypting data, [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) is employed. That means a random symmetric key is created, the data is encrypted with symmetric encryption (AES) and the symmetric key is encrypted with asymmetric encryption (RSA). The two encryptions are packaged together.
3. The data size RSA can encrypt is less than the key size. Even for raw RSA a 1024-bit key is limited to less than 127-bytes.

   In the code the key is 1024 **bits** (`[kSecAttrKeySizeInBits] = 1024`), which is 128 **bytes**. Accounting for 11-bytes of padding the largest data that can be encrypted is 116 bytes.
4. The real point is why use RSA (asymmetric) vs AES (symmetric) key encryption?

   In general asymmetric encryption such as RSA is not used to encrypt data, data is in general encrypted with symmetric encryption such as AES.The choice usually boils down to the need for separate encryption and decryption keys and/or PKI.

   Both are as secure at comparable key sizes and AES is much faster. Comparable key sizes: AES 128-bits, RSA 3072-bits. See [NIST: Recommendation for Key Management](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-57pt1r4.pdf) Table 2.

Comment: My code is work for first time. please see the gif ( I add it.) and run the project and test it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Thank you very much. but I check it, I check many times the keys, the keys same, that's point!

Comment: If you don't save the keys between executions they will be different and the decryption will fail as you see. Additionally this usage of RSA is not the accepted solution for data larger then the the key, the generally accepted solution is to use either symmetric encryption or is separate encryption snd decryption keys are required hybrid encryption.